# Network filesystem won't mount at boot

Tags: ldap, boot, fstab, linuxmint

We are running a lab network with a centralized file server. I recently installed Linux Mint on a new client computer and set up `LDAP` for user management and network folders through the `fstab`. When booting, the login screen appears and accepts users and passwords correctly but the home folders and others listed in the `fstab` are not mounted. Only when I manually run `mount -a` are the folders mounted successfully. So it seems that at the time `fstab` is called the network connection is not up yet?

I've tried adding a `mount -a` script to `/etc/network/if-up.d/`, but then the network fails to start completely.

Any ideas how I can ensure that the network is up when fstab is called?

Comment: Did you try adding "/bin/mount -a" in /etc/rc.local ? It is not the most recommended way of doing it, but you might try it.

Comment: @Danielt.Thanks a lot! It seems to work. Why would this not be a recommended way?

Comment: Mounting file systems is mainly done by adding entries to /etc/fstab, so unless you document this and every one in your team is aware of this, other admins might not check /etc/rc.local instantly. For a complete list of the do and don't of /etc/rc.local check this link http://sys-log.bencane.com/2011/12/when-its-ok-and-not-ok-to-use-rc-local/

Comment: If that helps you resolve the issue, keep it then. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding "/bin/mount -a" in /etc/rc.local